# Enlarge the current symbol

Tags: symbols

How can I write a code where I can adjust the height and size of the current symbol without using a `scalebox`? I tried one but it didn't work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardlessthanequal=\mathcode`<=
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecolessthanequal}{
\mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@lessthanequal\relax}
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@lessthanequal}[2]{
\raisebox{-0.1\height}{\scalebox{2.35}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\standardlessthanequal$}}
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`<= \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecolessthanequal
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`<="8000 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[\leq\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you still using two accounts?

Comment: your example gives errors on the completely unrelate ``\begingroup\lccode`~=`<= \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecolessthanequal
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`<="8000 }`` which appears to be trying to define < to be \leq  but can be removed, as can tikz which just slows down the test for anyone trying to help

Comment: also don't forget space characters at ends of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can guess you were attempting to define a mathcode for `<=` but that is two characters not one so is a syntax error, you can simply delete all the mathcode settings

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecolessthanequal}{%%%%
\mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@lessthanequal\relax}%%%%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@lessthanequal}[2]{%%%%
\raisebox{-0.1\height}{\scalebox{2.35}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\leq$}}%%%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[\leq\tauyecolessthanequal\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle But when I type ```\leq```, I want the enlarged symbol to appear on the screen.

Comment: @Pitaya88 well in that case add `\oldleq\leq` at the start and use \oldleq in the definition and call the new command \leq

Comment: Yes I did thanks @David Carlisle